# Appending element to the sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

how to append element  into the closest  on clicking "add-picture" button?

This is the html structure:

```
 <div class="step"
   <div class="step-wrapper>
     <div class="editor"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="delete-picture">
   <div class="add-picture">
 </div>

 <div class="step"
   <div class="step-wrapper>
     <div class="editor"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="delete-picture">
   <div class="add-picture">
 </div>

 <div class="step"
   <div class="step-wrapper>
     <div class="editor"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="delete-picture">
   <div class="add-picture">
 </div>
```

and here is my wrong jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-picture', function() {
    var imageField = $('<img class="link" >');
    $(this).parent().find(".step-wrapper").after(imageField);   
});
```

after click .step should look like:

```
  <div class="step"
       <div class="step-wrapper>
          <img class="link" >
         <div class="editor"></div>
       </div>

       <div class="delete-picture">
       <div class="add-picture">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `.prepnd()`, not `.after()` to make it the first child element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-picture', function() {
    var imageField = $('<img class="link" >');
    $(this).parent().find(".step-wrapper").prepend(imageField);   
});
```

See the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) for `.prepend()`.

Though this style of code works, you could also use `.closest()` for slightly more robust code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-picture', function() {
    var imageField = $('<img class="link" >');
    $(this).closest(".step").find(".step-wrapper").prepend(imageField);   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of `after()`:

```
$(this).parent().find(".step-wrapper").prepend(imageField);
```

`after()` places the content as a sibling whereas `prepend()` makes it the first child element

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to add the element before the `.editor` element, so try

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-picture', function() {
    var imageField = $('<img class="link" >');
    $(this).parent().find(".step-wrapper .editor").before(imageField);   
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eCjwy/)

Answer (score 1):

**2 Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/E78VA/1/ & http://jsfiddle.net/E78VA/

Also plz note your html DOM was not right and have few minor mistakes I have rectified ur HTML as well. i.e. missing end `div` etc. `:)`

`APIs` *could be used are*

- `prependTo` http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/
- `prepend` http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Hope rest fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-picture', function () {
    var imageField = $('<img class="link" >');
    // $(this).parent().find(".step-wrapper").prepend(imageField); 
    $(imageField).prependTo($(this).parent().find(".step-wrapper"));
    alert($(this).parent().find(".step-wrapper").html());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="step">
    <div class="step-wrapper">
        <div class="editor">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="delete-picture">delete</div>
    <div class="add-picture">add</div>
</div>
<div class="step">
    <div class="step-wrapper">
        <div class="editor"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="delete-picture"></div>
    <div class="add-picture"></div>
</div>
<div class="step">
    <div class="step-wrapper">
        <div class="editor"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="delete-picture"></div>
    <div class="add-picture"></div>
</div>
```